# How in JS to compare from an array of objects from all the results 2 keys are equal to 2 other variables

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how to get from an array of objects 2 specific keys and compare them with 2 other values for a boolean statement.

What I need to achieve is that for all results from an array of objects I have to check if
`ownerId` or `ownerType` are equal to example `this.ownerId` or `this.ownerType`.

To give an example I have a result Obj as

```
const results = [
    {
        ownerId: '1'
        ownerType: SOME_TYPE,
        id: 1
        ...
        <other key_values>
        ...
    },
    {
        ownerId: '1'
        ownerType: SOME_TYPE,
        id: 2
        ...
        <other key_values>
        ...
    },
    ... more ...
];
```

From the results, I have to extract all `ownerId` and `ownerType` and check if all are equal to another value as example

```
(ownerType === 'USER' && ownerId === userId) ||
(ownerType === 'PARTICIPANT' && ownerId === participantId)
```

So that means where `all ownerType === 'USER' && all ownerId === to this userId` then is true.

like all `ownerId` in my examples are 1 and we suppose 'USER' as a type then that is true.

but

If the result doesn't have all the same `ownerId` that is false.

I'm not sure what kind of function I need to write for it.

If any comments I'll try to explain better m issue

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through all the items and check them 1 by 1, when you find an item that doesn't pass, set the resultBoolean to false & stop the loop. When it goes through all the items witheout setting the boolean to false, everything passed.

```
let resultBoolean = true; 
const userId = '5';

for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { //loop through all the array items
    if (results[i].ownerId !== userId || results[i].ownerType !== "USER") { //check if this item doesn't have the specified requirements
        resultBoolean = false; //if it doesn't you know that not all items have the correct ownerId & ownerType
        break; //no need to continue looking because we already know its false
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer had also commented in another answer some thoughts.
I believe this is not complete but I may be wrong so I'll expose what I'm expecting as a result.
When all type result === USER && all ownerId result === external.userId 
OR
When all type result === PARTICIPANT && all ownerId result === extrnal.participantId 

The result of the function should be true or false based if one of those is true or false as OR works. I believe this you did only does for one case.

Comment: @Jakub This is outside the scope of this answer/question. You are asking basic programming questions. Just do an OR

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you might want to go with the `filter` method here

```
const concernedUsers = results.filter((user) => {
    // Fail if there's no ownerType or userId
    if (!user.ownerType || !user.userId) return false;
    // Check for USER/PARTICIPANT type and userId/ownerId
    return
        ['USER', 'PARTICIPANT'].indexOf(user.ownerType) > -1 && 
        ownerID === user.userId;
});
concernedUsers.map((user) => { /*do something*/ });
```

Comment: So the idea is I have to keep that 'or' which means the statement needs to be as

Comment: So the idea is I have to keep that 'or' which means the statement needs to be as 
USER && ownerId === this.userId 
OR
PARTICIPANT && ownerId === this.userId 

So if the first one pass is true or if the second one is a true pass

The result need to be a boolean no data back as a map.

I have to give back true of the comparison if all the results have the same userId or participantId based on those 2 cases.

when USER and all ownerId are equal to userId
OR
when PARTICIPANT and all ownerId are equal to partecipantId

Not sure this is doing that maybe I miss understand

Comment: Oooh my bad, let me fix it

Comment: Here it check both USER and OWNER and does a second check for ownerId since both verifications require ownerId = user.userID

Comment: I believe we are close the thing is userId and partecdipantId are external values.
From the result object, I get only ownerId, ownerType and some other stuff. 
so the comparison is between the ownerId coming from the result and the userId and partecipantId coming from another source.
Remaining an or situation still

Comment: Another thing is that I'm expecting that the output of the function is like concernedUsers = boolean true/false because I'm only saying false/true and no need for the data to be mapped. 
The result to be clear need to be output as true or false only

Comment: Then you should definetly go with @Laurent Dhont 's method. What you are trying to do is more efficient with a `for` loop, while the `.map` method is easier to read, it doesn't have the `break` instruction, meaning you will loop through the whole array, whereas the `for` and `break` way to do it will stop the loop once it founds a match